# Finding the lowest combination of M digits ranging from X to Y that when summed adds up to at least N

Tags: algorithms

Is there a known procedure for finding the lowest combination of M digits ranging from X to Y where (X <= Y) so that when summed adds up to at least N.
Keep in mind, I am saying combination, not permutation, so order does not matter.
By convention to find the lowest combination, I will be arranging the digits from high to low.
An example of what I mean

6 digits, ranging from 0 to 6 - what is the lowest combination so that when each digit is added, the sum is guaranteed to be 28 or higher.

I always iterate to a solution but I haven't been able to codify it in a neater algorithm than the one below.

In this example -  I just do the following:

```
666640 // Max out all the slots
666550 // Shifting ones to any number on the right as long as the number to the right is <= to its neighbor to the left
666541
666532
665542
665533
665443
664444
655444
555544 // answer
```

I ran a bit of code brute forcing it and I got the same sequence.
Is my algorithm correct in all cases? Is this a known technique I can lookup properly?

For context - I am running a scientific simulation where I have to find all the ways to sum up to >= N in M digits. In reality, I have many more digits, so reducing the run time of this step can speed up my overall run time

Comment: What does "lowest combination" mean exactly? Does it mean that combination, whose permutation is the lowest?

Comment: Yeah, the combination when arranged from highest digit to lowest digit is the lowest number